# How can i use corretly Latex notation via forEach function in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, render

I have array examples where i have example (ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0), example (ax^2 + 9x +9 = 0) etc.

I have following logic

```
const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");
    examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
      const example = `
        <div class="card">
          <div class="example">
          ${ex.question}
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="toggle" onclick="toggle(${i})">
            Toggle
          </button>
          <div id="result_${i}" style="display:none" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
        </div>`;
      container.innerHTML += example;
    });
```

Somehow is not working i get only string with array value and nothing else. `<p>(ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0)</p>` Works well

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating `container.innerHTML` with each example, compose first the html of all examples, and add that to the container:

```js
const examples = [
  { question: '(ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0)', answer: '(answer for ax^2 + 5x +1 = 0)'},
  { question: '(ax^2 + 9x +9 = 0)', answer: '(answer for ax^2 + 9x +9 = 0)'},
];

function toggle(i) {
  const div = document.querySelector(`#result_${i}`);
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
      div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
      div.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

let html = '';
examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
  const example = `
    <div class="card">
      <div class="example">
      ${ex.question}
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="toggle" onclick="toggle(${i})">
        Toggle
      </button>
      <div id="result_${i}" style="display:none" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
    </div>`;
  html += example;
});
const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");
//console.log(html);
container.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
.card {
  border: solid gray 1px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="examples-container"></div>
```

Comment: Ou sorry my bad. I forgot to tell i use MathJax to display examples. In DOM it's not in mjx-container which is responsible for rendering. Do u guess why is that please?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If you have 2 containers you could create `html1` and `html2`, then add that to the two containers.

Comment: Also, for better performance try to avoid updating the DOM as much as possible, e.g. instead of updating the DOM in a loop, it is better to create the HTML in the look, then update the DOM with one call.